# I got a memory leak and the responsible frame is strdup. who can give me some clues?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, memory-leaks

I got a memory leak when I detect with instrument. I don`t have so much experience about memory-management, so I can not figure out what is the possible cause for this problem, the memory leak is as below:

[image]

[image]

I want to know the possible reason about this kind of memory leak. Is some one who can give me some clues?

Answer (score 2):

`strdup` uses `malloc` internally, so anything that has been `strdup`-ed has to be freed using `free`.

For example:

```
char *duplicate = strdup("abcdef");
...
free(duplicate);
```

Comment: I have search through my project, I never use strdup explicitly

Answer (score 1):

`strdup()` is a library function, so you need to go back up the backtrace until you find a caller that's in *your* code.  There you'll find a library call which is resulting in memory being allocated - it should have a corresponding freeing call elsewhere in your program.

(The freeing function is not necessarily a direct call to `free()` - for example if you call the `getaddrinfo()` library function the corresponding freeing function is `freeaddrinfo()`).

Comment: True. But maybe you should say why?